# setOnItemSelectedListener not called on tablet

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, spinner

I have two layouts for mobile and tablet, both called from single code.

```
...
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_font_sizes"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:entries="@array/lst_editor_font_sizes" />
...
```

In both these layouts I have defined a hidden Spinner, the following code works on phone, but not on tablet:
the spinner shows on phone, but clicking on it doesn't fire the listener event.

```
spin_font_sizes=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_font_sizes);
        spin_font_sizes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // THIS IS NOT CALLED ON PHONE!
                Resources res=getResources();
                String[] arr = res.getStringArray(R.array.lst_editor_font_sizes);
                float size= Float.parseFloat(arr[arg2]);
                editor.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT,size);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Abrar.Editor", 0);
                Editor edt = settings.edit();
                edt.putFloat("editorFontSize", size);
                edt.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Sometimes I see this error in log:

```
03-30 11:03:03.528: W/InputEventReceiver(8958): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: so do you suggest that Spinners are not working on your phone?

Comment: yes, the spinner shows, but clicking on it doesn't fire the listener event.

Comment: did you debug it with a debugger since i dont see any Log.* calls ?

Comment: @pskink yes, I debugged it.

Comment: and you are sure that ssetOnItemSelectedListener was called ?